# DropDownList in .NET FormView loads perfectly the first time, never again

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, formview

I build a `DataTable` and populate it with a country abbreviation and country expansion. I make this the DataSource for a `DropDownList` control within a `FormView`. To see this `FormView`, the user clicks a button on the form. The DropDownList is always correctly populated *the first time*. After dealing with this `FormView` (to add a record to the data store), the user must click the same button he previously clicked, to add another record, but the `DropDownList` is *never* populated. I have confirmed that the DataTable feeding this list is populated at each invocation. Of course, the code is also exactly the same.

The form code looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstBornIn" runat="server" />
```

and the code-behind looks like this:

```
  tblCountry = (DataTable) Session["tblCountry"];
DropDownList lstBorn = (DropDownList) 
FormView1.FindControl("lstBornIn");
lstBorn.DataSource = tblCountry;
lstBorn.DataValueField = "Abbrev";
lstBorn.DataTextField = "Country";
lstBorn.DataBind();
```

As noted, this works perfectly the first time, but never again. It appears to be a binding problem, as the Items list is empty upon subsequent invocations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When do you bind the data to your dropdown list? Can you post the full method for your button clicked method?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not a recommended practice to store large objects in the Session variables. And "tblCountry" does not seem to be a small one.

Comment: Be that as it may, aleafonso, I have checked that DataTable upon each invocation, and it always has its 67 items (I limit the country list to 67).

Comment: I should add that, following various suggestions around the Internet, I substituted such mechanisms as Hashtable for the DataTable scheme, but behavior is identical: fine the first time, no list items on any subsequent appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving up on this, and just want to report on what else I've done to resolve this.

One thought was that the problem I am seeing occurs only within Visual Studio, so I established the relevant files on IIS7, and tried it with the three major browsers. All failed identically.

The most incredible thing (to me) is that when I look at one of the lists using the VS debugger, it has all 67 items neatly tucked away. It just won't show them.

My workaround is simple enough: hard-code the list items in the ASPX file. Looks ugly but works just fine.

I'll be on the lookout for anything that suggests a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ViewState turned off for the page or the DropDownList or another control in the DDL's hierarchy? If so, you will either have to turn it back on or else rebind on postbacks.

Comment: No, ViewState is not off. The code noted above runs every time the FormView is instantiated, and the DataTable is confirmed to be populated at that time.